# Connect to PostgreSQL from C++ (gcc)

Tags: c++, postgresql, gcc

How I can to connect PostgreSQL in a console C++ programm, which header files I must to include etc?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/libpq.html

Answer (score 1):

This is official documentation of libpq.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/libpq.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try third-party C++ libraries for database connectivity like [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/)